# How correct issues in Qt Android Compile?

Tags: android, c++, qt, compiler-errors, qml

I'm creating a new app for Android using Qt.
But when i search to compile an example i have no problem, but when i search to compile a simple app created by me i have some compile issues.

```
  -- Skipping C:/Qt/5.15.0/android/plugins/iconengines/libplugins_iconengines_qsvgicon_armeabi-v7a.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg_armeabi-v7a.so,lib/libQt5Widgets_armeabi-v7a.so.
  -- Skipping C:/Qt/5.15.0/android/plugins/imageformats/libplugins_imageformats_qsvg_armeabi-v7a.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg_armeabi-v7a.so,lib/libQt5Widgets_armeabi-v7a.so.
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Fusion.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Fusion.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Imagine.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Imagine.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Imagine.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE

> Task :compileDebugAidl FAILED
aidl.exe E 07-06 14:01:58 10104  4764 io_delegate.cpp:50] Failed to GetFullPathName(C:\Users\polly\OneDrive\Documenti\LaboratorioQT_definizione\build-ArquatoApo-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out\org\kde\necessitas\ministro\IMinistro.java)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\polly\Android\sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\polly\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\polly\OneDrive\Documenti\LaboratorioQT_definizione\build-ArquatoApo-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out -IC:\Users\polly\OneDrive\Documenti\LaboratorioQT_definizione\build-ArquatoApo-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\src -IC:\Users\polly\OneDrive\Documenti\LaboratorioQT_definizione\build-ArquatoApo-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Qt\5.15.0\android\src\android\java\src -IC:\Users\polly\OneDrive\Documenti\LaboratorioQT_definizione\build-ArquatoApo-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\aidl -dC:\Users\polly\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl2002872346066390839.d C:\Qt\5.15.0\android\src\android\java\src\org\kde\necessitas\ministro\IMinistro.aidl}


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
14:01:58: The process "C:\Qt\5.15.0\android\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project ArquatoApo (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.15.0 for Android))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
14:01:58: Elapsed time: 00:20.
```

What i can do? Where i Wrong?

Comment: It could be the path is too long (by default the max probably is 260 characters): `(C:\Users\polly\OneDrive\Documenti\LaboratorioQT_definizione\build-ArquatoApo-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out\org\kde\necessitas\ministro\IMinistro.java`

Comment: `Failed to GetFullPathName` ... the error is pretty clear. As @drescherjm already noticed the path probably is too long. Are you sure you've set it right?